# Sketching functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

1) The functions $f$ and $g$ are as follows.
$$f(x) = x^2 + 4x,\; x≥-2$$
$$g(x) = x + 6 ,\;x\in \mathbb R$$ 
i) Show that the equation $g\circ f(x)= 0$ has no real roots.

*$g\circ f(x)=(x^2 + 4x) + 6 (x^2+4x)$* correct?

So the minimum value does not occur, correct?  Thus having no function?

2) UNRELATED QUESTION: Given that $f(x) = cos x$, for the domain $0 ≤ x ≤ K$ find the largest value of $k$ for which $f$ has an inverse.

How do i approach this question?

Thank you so much!  And again, apologies if the chain of thought I have provided is stupid.

Comment: Is $g(x)$ really $x+6x$?  seems like an odd way to write $7x$.

Comment: Also...I don't follow your argument for the non-existence of a root.  Your equation, $7x^2+28x=0$ certainly does have a real root...two of them!  I can see why you reject one of them, but not the other..  But I expect the definition of $g(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: I'll guess:  $g(x)=x+6$.  Then $g\circ f(x)=x^2+4x+6=(x+2)^2+2$.

Comment: Mr "Anderson" Is it really $x+6$ or $x+6x$ (which would be strange as @lulu abserved). Now that 50 minutes have ellapsed, you have to confirm or infirm.

Comment: Any chance of getting this question clarified?  If not, I think it should be closed.

Comment: My apologies @lulu it is x+6 NOT x+6x.  I have gone ahead and edited the qion.

Comment: Unrelated questions should be posed separately.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the functions
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^2 + 4x, x \geq -2\\
g(x) & = x + 6, x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
The composition $g \circ f$ is 
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = g(f(x))\\
               & = g(x^2 + 4x), x \geq -2\\
               & = x^2 + 4x + 6, x \geq -2
\end{align*}
where we replace each occurrence of $x$ in the formula for $g(x)$ with $x^2 + 4x$ for each $x$ in the domain of $f$, that is, for $x \geq -2$.

> Show that the equation $(g \circ f)(x) = 0$ has no real roots.

Since $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 4x + 6$, we must show that the equation 
$$x^2 + 4x + 6 = 0, x \geq -2$$
has no real-valued solutions in $[-2, \infty)$.  The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) of the quadratic equation is 
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 4^2 - 4(1)(6) = 16 - 24 = -8$$ 
Since $\Delta < 0$, the quadratic equation has no real roots, as you can verify by solving the equation by completing the square or using the Quadratic Formula.

Alternatively, we can complete the square on $(g \circ f)(x) = x^2 + 4x + 6$ to obtain its vertex form.
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = x^2 + 4x + 6, x \geq -2\\
               & = x^2 + 4x + 4 - 4 + 6, x \geq -2\\
               & = (x + 2)^2 + 2, x \geq -2
\end{align*}
The equation $y = (x + 2)^2 + 2$ describes a parabola with vertex $(-2, 2)$ that opens upwards.  The restriction that $x \geq -2$ means we only have the right half of the parabola.  As you can see from its graph, the function never equals zero.

[image: graph_of_restricted_quadratic_function]

> Given that $f(x) = \cos x$, $0 \leq x \leq k$, find the largest value of $k$ for which $f$ has an inverse.

If a function has an inverse, then we can express $x$ as a function of $y$.  Consequently, there can be at most one $x$-value for each $y$-value of the function.  This means that if a function has an inverse, a horizontal line can intersect its graph at most once.  This theorem is called the [Horizontal Line Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test).  Now, look at the graph of $y = \cos x, x \geq 0$.

[image: restricted_cosine_graph]

What is the largest value of $k$ to the right of $x = 0$ such that a horizontal line intersects the graph of $f(x) = \cos x, 0 \leq x \leq k$, at most once?